# Bile file output to text file not structured

Tags: batch-file

I am running these two commands `net users >> out.txt` and `wmic qfe list full >>out.txt` in a batch file. After doing so, the output of the wmic command displays null characters after every other character. Is there a way I can fix this? When i output those two commands info in separate text files, the output is perfectly fine. I am super confused about this as to why this is happening

Comment: Depending on your formatting needs, `%__APPDIR__%wbem\WMIC.exe qfe list full /format:texttablewsys` may also help.

Answer (score 3):

`wmic` uses little-endian UTF-16 to display its output, while `net users` uses regular ANSI. In UTF-16, each character is two bytes long, and the standard ASCII character set is its regular ASCII value followed by a null byte.

When you run `net users >> out.txt` first, you force the output file to not be a UTF-16-encoded file, so the output of the `wmic` command is not displayed correctly. (Incidentally, if you simply tried to swap the order of the commands, you'd find that the `net users` command would appear as Chinese characters.)

The only way to get `wmic` output into ANSI is to run it through multiple `for /f` loops:

```
net users >> out.txt
for /f "delims=" %A in ('wmic qfe list full') do for /f "delims=" %B in ("%~A") do echo %B >> out.txt
```

Note that if you're putting this in a script, you need to use `%%A` and `%%B` instead of `%A` and `%B`.

Comment: `The only way` seems a little rash to me, dark one. Perhaps `wmic qfe list full | more>>out.txt` would work. Does for me...

Comment: @Magoo - Does it? That's good to know; I've only ever seen nested `for` loops (one for the initial conversion and one to get rid of the `ECHO is OFF` statements) used to parse `wmic`.

Comment: @Magoo is correct, simply doing `(net users && wmic qfe list full | more)>out.txt` works.

Comment: @Magoo I feel, the `more` trick deserves its own answer. (Btw: `|find /v ""`?  instead of `more` works too and might be better with big outputs (>64k)

Answer (score 3):

`wmic` uses a different character set and has some additional CRLF in it's output. One way is to use a for loop:

from `cmd`

```
(net users && @for /F "delims=" %i in ('wmic qfe list full') do @echo(%i)>out.txt
```

In a `batch-file`

```
(net users && @for /F "delims=" %%i in ('wmic qfe list full') do @echo(%%i)>out.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a different command completely, net.exe is not really needed for the results you need.

```sh
@%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe /Output:"out.txt" UserAccount Get Name
@%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe /Append:"out.txt" QFE List Full 1>NUL
```

You could even run just a single command, instead of two, which should considerably speed up the process too:

```sh
@(Echo /Output:"out.txt" UserAccount Get Name & Echo /Append:"out.txt" QFE List Full) | %SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe 1>NUL
```